# How Can I disable streaming for the Mule SFTP connector

Tags: mule

How can be disabled the Mule SFTP connector streaming functionality, I don't find the property for this

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why would you like to disable streaming. If it only that you are unable to handle and process stream in your application and you want to transform the stream to object for processing, you can consider transforming stream data to object by using byte array to object transformer.

Comment: Yes, as you said, I can't handle and process stream in my app, I will check out transforming to object using the byte array to object transformer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can increase polling frequency time. So mule streaming in fixed time period.

```
<sftp:inbound-endpoint host="${ftp.host}" port="${ftp.port}"
            path="${ftp.inboundTSPpath}" user="${ftp.inbound.username}" password="${ftp.inbound.password}"
            doc:name="FTP" **pollingFrequency="${ftp.tspPollingFrequency}"**
            encoding="UTF-8">

        </sftp:inbound-endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Streaming is good and it is provided by default. It is so good that Mulesoft did not provide clear way to stream/unstream - they believe everything should be stream only.

Sometimes we need to unstream for different reasons. We may rely on some side effects on some actions. Usually simple converting to Json or other type may solve the issue.
Sometime it could be enforced by adding attribute deferred.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json deferred=false
```

Each stream is different and may be unstreamed in different way.